# How to enable the REST Record Service (Beta) features

Tags: netsuite

I’m trying to learn Rest Web for some features. Currently, I want to test “customerPayment” feature. When I test it on my postman, display error detail.

> The customerPayment record is only available as a beta record. Enable the REST Record Service (Beta) feature in Setup > Company > Enable Features to work with this record.

I’m checking on my “Enable Features” page, but I could found “REST Record Service (Beta)” features. How suppose I can enable that feature?

My current Netsuite account is "NetSuite Umbrella Beta Program". But i not sure does Rest Record Service already include.

Please help

Answer (score 3):

I am sure you have found this out by now but for all future inquiries, once you navigate to Setup > Company > Enable Features there should be a blue information message on the top of the screen that ask if you want to opt in to beta features.

[image]